# How to align vertically multiple cards with different heights

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er9go.png)

Please refer above image, I tried to use flex but I can not get the result that I expected.

I'm working on tailwind css. I want to be the result like green cards in the image. Example to understand much appropriate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with previous answer that CSS [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) are best for these designs.

Below is an example using columns in TailwindCSS.  Refer to the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/columns) for additional examples.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="columns-3 gap-5 p-5">
  <img class="w-full rounded-lg mb-5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/800/600" />
  <img class="w-full rounded-lg mb-5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/800" />
  <img class="w-full rounded-lg mb-5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/900" />
  <img class="w-full rounded-lg mb-5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/55/800/600" />
  <img class="w-full rounded-lg mb-5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/36/800" />
  <img class="w-full rounded-lg mb-5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/92/900/1100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use columns for this, in css when you use flex, flexbox, or grid there is no way to have different heights inside 1 row, but if you use seperate columns that are vertical, and set the parent of all columns to a flex element you will achieve the results.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im sorry im new to this. can you provide me an example?

Comment: I have added an example in the answer